# Before CSS, how one would change margins and paddings?

Tags: html, css

CSS is quite recent.

Nowadays, in it's 3rd version, it is supported and used in many places!

Even parts of it (the selectors) are used on other languages!

But CSS wasn't always around.

Before those times where CSS brough a fresh breeze, how one would change a simple margin or a padding?

---

I know that `<table>`s have `cellspacing` and `cellpadding`, but other tags like `<img>`, `<span>`, `<b>`, `<label>`.... don't have such property.

The intention is to use the knowledge gathered here to use for emails and to kill my curiosity. Sadly, this time, a kitten couldn't do it.

Comment: Not so recent. [CSS level 1 W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1-961217) (1996) has [`margin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1-961217#margin) and [`padding`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1-961217#padding).

Comment: CSS is not recent.  HTML is on version 5 but still not recent.  The internet itself on the grand scheme of things is still quite new.  But these languages have been around since the www.

Comment: Compared to IE3, it is recent.... And it wasn't entirely supported by then. Even today, after many years, parts of it aren't well supported in some browsers. For example, paddings in `<tr>`'s don't work.

Comment: And they shouldn't since a TD dictates that.

Comment: @Rafael Css came **after** the internet was 'invented'...

Comment: having such difficulties css was introduced..

Comment: I never said it wasn't creater **after** the internet I said www.  There is a difference.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#History

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I know *why*  it was introduced, I'm interested on *how*   they did *before* there was CSS,

Comment: if you want to know how they did before just write a HTML doc without CSS and wala.

Comment: @Rafael -.- that doesn't answer...

Comment: It really does answer your question.  Just write an HTML document in the first DOCTYPE HTML ever had and you'll find your answer...

Comment: @Rafael it still doesn't tell me *how* a padding on a `<p>` tag (for example) was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to be curious.

1. CSS is old. It was created right after HTML. Because... people wanted this margin and padding.
2. You could add some more whitespaces. Guess what: noobs are still doing that today!

```html
<P>Lorem ipsum</P>
<BR><!--I call this-->
<BR><!--"Boom Boroom Buroom!"-->
<BR><!--Obvious reference to Lord of the Rings is obvious.-->
<P>Haha. margin!</P>
```

Satisfied? If not, read [HTML 2.0 spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt). That was before CSS. :)

### Edit

As you mentioned:

```html
<P>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; If somebody use this, a say &ndash; No Bull Sh*t Please. It's an acronym, right? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</P>
```

Idea of hipertext, the H.T. in HTML, apeared in 40's. HTML was created to share scientific documents. You don't need decoration for that. It's important to understand the history of the web, not just to know about it. I personaly think, that internet for everyone started with CSS and `<img>` tag, but nowadays we often get lost in all of this decoration. Take a look at [motherf***ingwebsite.com](http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/)

Comment: I'm somewhat satisfied... At least I got an answer! And a load of downvotes and an angry "mob". But I was expecting something more interesting. The `<br>` 'trick' is.... scary.... and that's me being nice! Also, following the whitespace logic, one could use the famous `&nbsp;`. Or vertical tabs. I've heard things like, using filler white images to ocupy a certain space in a table. And tables with tables inside.... Horrorous horrors! Like I said, I was expecting an exciting trick.